# save receveid message to variable with telegram-cli lua script

Tags: variables, lua, match, sh, whitespace

im trying to send the message content in a variable to an sh script, to trigger this i start the telegram message with the word "test"

i have this in my lua script that i run with telegram on my odroid

```
-- TEST:
action, variable=msg.text:match("+ %b %s")
if (action=='test' or action=='Test') then
os.execute(string.format("/home/scripts/test.sh \"%s\" &",variable))
```

if i send: "test i want this text in the variable"
via telegram to the odroid, it does nothing.
i have tried a lot of variations on ("+ %b %s") however it does not work
any idea what im doing wrong?

ps. the trigger word "test" must not be saved to the variable

Comment: `variable = msg.text:match"^[Tt]est%s*(.*)$"; if variable then os.execute(....) end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff

that is great! thank you, is there anyway i can keep the spaces the output is now: iwantthistextinthevariable
in stead of: i want this text in the variable
cheers.

Comment: To remove spaces: `variable = variable:gsub("%s", "")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff no i want to keep the spaces :)

Comment: Where do you see a text without spaces?  If you're passing this string to a shell command, please wrap your string in single quotes.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff
could you show me how? 

variable = msg.text:match"^[Tt]est%s*(.*)$";
if variable then os.execute(string.format("/home/scripts/test.sh \"%s\" &",variable))
end

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to pass a string as command line parameter is the following:

```
variable = msg.text:match"^[Tt]est%s*(.*)$"
if variable then 
  os.execute("/home/scripts/test.sh '"..variable:gsub("'", "'\\''").."'&") 
end
```

How does `test.sh` processing the string?  The problem of disappearing spaces might be there.